# Chart.ux.Highcharts how to get work with simple store

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4, highcharts, store

i'm trying to use Highcharts plugin and I've started with the simple example in his documentation
I've correctly set the enviroment (I'm sure).
This is the windows i've declared:

```
//other part of app.js (working)
launch:function():{
var sto = Ext.create('AM.store.mysto');
var win = new Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
       xtype: 'highchart',
       series:[{
          dashStyle: 'DashDot',
          dataIndex: 'value'
       }],
       xField: 'month',
       store: sto,
       chartConfig: {
          chart: {
             type: 'spline'
          },
          title: {
             text: 'A simple graph'
          }
       }
    }]
}).show();
//other part of app.js (working)
}
//........more other part of app.js (working)
```

and I've declared the store as follow:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.mysto', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
  model : 'AM.model.mysto',
  data : [{
    month : 'x',
    value:1
  }, {
    month : 'y',
    value:12,

    value:2
  }, {
    month : 'z',
    value:3
  }]
});
```

And finally this is my model:

```
Ext.define('AM.model.mysto', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields : [{
    name : 'month'
  }, {
    name : 'value'
  }]
});
```

If I execute my application, this will be my window: an empty window with no chart inside.

[image: the window]

The only difference I've with the doc example is the store. Can someone tell me what is wrong? 
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the guru of Sencha "mitchellsimoens" said:
"You have layout : 'fit' on the window which will size the child item to the window's size so you would need to give the window a size."

it's true. I've added the size and it works fine:

```
  var win = new Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    layout: 'fit',

//HERE!!!!
      width: 200,
      height: 200,

    items: [{
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not a window size actually, 
the problem is - window empty and no chart inside 
have the same issue by the way

in the original example the store not loaded, and even autoload in store is not a case for you

```
, autoLoad: true
```

cause you should create window only after store loaded with data or reload a store after window creation
that way I would do it something like this

```
var chartStore = Ext.create('chartStore'); 
chartStore.load({

    callback: function (data, operation, success) {

        // here the store is loaded with data already 
        var winChart = new Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            width: 400 
            , height: 400
            , layout: 'fit' 
            items: [{
                xtype: 'highchart' 
                , series: [{
    }
```

moreover this can be an idea as well 
Chart.ux.Highcharts >>> initAnimAfterLoad

> Since Highcharts initial and update animations are not the same, if you want to make sure there is initial animation, then you should create store and extension in specific sequence. First, set the Ext.data.Store.autoLoad option to false, create the Highcharts component with the store, then call the Ext.data.Store.load method. The initAnimAfterLoad defers creating the chart internally until the store is loaded. Disabling it, the extension will create the chart instantly and you will only see the update animation after the load.

also this store param give more info in console

```
, debug: true
```

**Solved with colleague's advice**
this should be added in store and that works like a charm

```
, autoLoad: true
```

thank you